# How to show all items by default when user hasn't filtered by category from dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First time trying this so please bear with me. For full code, codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ex1yc?file=/src/components/SearchFilter.js).

I have a dropdown that filters products based on category. Currently on load, the project doesn't display products. It's only when you select a category, the products load in.

I'd like to show all products on project load with an 'All' option in the dropdown. And then when a user selects a category, filter the products.

Wrote some code below. When adding the if(!selectedCategory).. statement, it throws an error of "TypeError: filteredCategories.map is not a function". If I remove the if statement, the project loads and I can filter by category, but it doesn't display all products on project load.

Code:

```
  // Load in global state
  const { data, isLoading } = useAPI();

  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");

  // DROPDOWN - filter based on category
  const filteredCategories = () => {
    if (!selectedCategory) { // <--- trying to return all products by default if user doesn't select a category
      return data;
    }
    return data.filter(
      (machine) =>
        machine.category.toLowerCase() === selectedCategory.toLowerCase()
    );
  };
```

Render code:

```
{/* Dropdown */}
<div className="options">
   {!isLoading ? (
   <>
   <select
      value={selectedCategory}
      onChange={(e) =>
      setSelectedCategory(e.target.value)}
      className="product-dropdown"
      name="product-dropdown"
      >
      {data.map((item) => (
      <option value={item.category}>{item.category}</option>
      ))}
   </select>
   </>
   ) : (
   <p>Loading...</p>
   )}
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to load in all products be default with an 'All' option in the dropdown, and then filter products by category when a user selects from the dropdown?

Comment: You should set the state as 'All' . const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("All"); And use this in your api.

Comment: Maybe with `null` check you can avoid that error message as `data && data.map()`.

Comment: Thanks @amardeepsaini. I've set the state to 'All'. What do you mean by 'use this in your api'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultValue`

```
<select
      value={selectedCategory}
      onChange={(e) =>
      setSelectedCategory(e.target.value)}
      className="product-dropdown"
      name="product-dropdown"
      defaultValue=""
      >
      <option value="">All</option>
      {data.map((item) => (
      <option value={item.category}>{item.category}</option>
      ))}
   </select>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikita, shows the option of All which is great. However which All selected, it doesn't show any products. How do I show all products when 'All' is selected?